# How to identify errors from casting a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling

I have a table that is all NVARCHAR. I am trying to cast a column into a date; however, there appears to be some value in the column that will not cast as date and is throwing an error halfway through.

I am trying to find the rows that are problematic. However, I don't know how to equal a result to an error..

```
SELECT id, 
CASE WHEN CAST(date_of_birth AS DATE) = error
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
FROM TABLE1
```

Table1

```
id    date_of_birth
1     05/05/1934
2     feathers
3     06/06/1843
```

Expected results

```
id    date_of_birth
1     0
2     1
3     0
```

Any advice on how to isolate the problematic rows?

Comment: Ughhh!  I am running in to the same issue right now. Look forward to the answer.

Comment: The best solution would be to start using proper datatypes instead of storing everything as varchar. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: @SeanLange you're telling me..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `TRY_CAST()`:

```
SELECT id, 
       (CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(date_of_birth AS DATE) IS NULL AND date_of_birth IS NOT NULL
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END) as is_bad_date_of_birth
FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: cast/try_cast does not throw error on `''` and converts it to 1900-01-01 so might want to check that as well.

Answer (score 1):

To identify error rows, use the ISDATE function:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ISDATE(date_of_birth)=0`

Comment: This can return false positives when the value has a date value with a format that is not the default.